# Performing Add-Content on a generated list of files

Tags: powershell

I am super new to PowerShell and scripting in general, but I need to make a script that will search through a directory, find all files with a certain extension (excluding files in certain directories) then edits each of those files with a text string.

Currently I am able to generate a list of all files in the locations I want, excluding the directories I want to ignore using the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\path\location\TEST\* -recurse -Exclude ROB | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer} | where {$_ -notmatch 'ROB'} | ?{$_.name -match “^*.cpp|h$”}
```

Now where I am struggling is to use the `add-content` cmdlet to add a string to the bottom of each file matching my query above. I've tried doing the following, but it does not work:

```
Add-Content {Get-ChildItem -path C:\path\location\TEST\* -recurse -Exclude ROB | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer} | where {$_ -notmatch 'ROB'} | ?{$_.name -match “^*.cpp|h$”}} "TextString"
```

This is the error I get:

```
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the answer here is to define the `get-childitem` command as a variable then just the variable as the location in `add-content` and viola! 

So it would look like

    $Query = Get-ChildItem -path C:\path\location\TEST\* -recurse -Exclude ROB | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer} | where {$_ -notmatch 'ROB'} | ?{$_.name -match “^*.cpp|h$”}
    add-content -path $Query "TextToAdd"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer here is to define the `get-childitem` command as a variable then just the variable as the location in `add-content` and viola!

So it would look like

```
$Query = Get-ChildItem -path C:\path\location\TEST\* -recurse -Exclude ROB | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer} | where {$_ -notmatch 'ROB'} | ?{$_.name -match “^*.cpp|h$”}
add-content -path $Query "Text"
```